# Выполнение запроса если строка в сравнении содержит перенос строки

Tags: sql, sql-server

Этот запрос не возвращает ни результата, ни ошибку:

```
SELECT [num_id] from obj.Objects  where [object_name] like  'РВС-20000 №1 ЛПДС "Платина" ПРНУ. Строительство'
```

А вот этот запрос работает нормально:

```
   SELECT [num_id] from obj.Objects  where [object_name] like  'РВС-20000 №1 ЛПДС "Платина" ПРНУ. Строительство
   '
```

Задачка из разряда найдите десять различий. На самом деле различие одно - во втором случае одинарная кавычка перенесена на следующую строку и только.

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый запрос возвращает пустой результат. Ошибку он не может возвращать, т.к. запрос корректный, но и данные он не может вернуть, т.к. в таблице нет соответствующей строки.

Перенос строки внутри константы означает символ/символы переноса строки. Значит у вас в базе лежит значение с переносом строки в конце строки.

Предложенный Igor'ем вариант не совсем корректен, т.к. % заменяет не только невидимые символы, но и обычные буквы. Если вдруг у вас появятся записи 'РВС-20000 №1 ЛПДС "Платина" ПРНУ. Строительство дорог' 'РВС-20000 №1 ЛПДС "Платина" ПРНУ. Строительство зданий', то все они будут выбраны этим запросом.

Правильное решение - использовать TRIM (посмотрите в справке как удалять не только пробелы, но и символы CHAR(10) и CHAR(13))

Еще более правильное решение - использовать TRIM перед вставкой в таблицу.

Answer (score 2):

Во втором случае строка в условии заканчивается символом переноса строки. И такие значения есть в таблице. Вы используете  `LIKE`, но знака `%` в выражении нет - строки проверяются на строгое равенство.

```
SELECT [num_id] from obj.Objects  where [object_name] like 
  'РВС-20000 №1 ЛПДС "Платина" ПРНУ. Строительство%'
```